Is it possible to have a giant floating banner that reads: "YOU MUST CITE YOUR CLAIMS […]"
If you haven't noticed, there's been a small spike in new responders lately, which is great!  However, it's not great that the majority of them are not citing any of their claims…many of which are suspect anyway (i.e., anecdotal, speculative, and conceptually confusing). (But even the apparently knowledgeable are light on their citations.)
I realize that perpetually being in beta prevents us from customizing the site, but is there a way to make the "CITE!!!" rule more conspicuous to new users?  

Maybe a gigantic, colorful floating banner?
Or some sort of box that pops up before you submit an answer?
Or some fancy auto-comment or reporting system that detects citation-less responses and makes a comment on, or reports, them?
Or some other crazy idea?

I imagine that most of the policing will be left to the users of this site, but some preventive or automatic strategies couldn't hurt--that is, if they're possible. ;)

Related: http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/426/do-we-want-a-warning-about-scientific-answers-before-users-answer

Telling people to cite stuff is literally 50% of the comments I make.
